# Spawn objects in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coordinates, game-development

I'm writting a small 2D game in Unity with C#. I have built two obstaclespawner which spawn vertical lines. After the lines have been spawned, they move down. One of the spawner is located at the upper left edge and the other one at the upper right edge. Currently, new objects are spawned after a certain time. But my goal is, for example, to spawn a new object on the upper left edge when the object which is spawned on the top right has traveled a certain distance.
Could this possibly be done via the coordinates of the objects?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ObstacleSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] obstacles;
    public List<GameObject> obstaclesToSpawn = new List <GameObject>();
    int index;

    void Awake()
    {
        InitObstacles();
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine (SpawnRandomObstacle ());
    }

    // Initialize obstacles
    void InitObstacles()
    {
        index=0;
        for(int i =0; i<obstacles.Length*3;i++){
        GameObject obj = Instantiate(obstacles[index], transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        obstaclesToSpawn.Add(obj);
        obstaclesToSpawn [i].SetActive (false);
        index++;

            if (index == obstacles.Length)
            {
                index= 0;
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator SpawnRandomObstacle()
    {
        //Wait a certain time
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
    }


            //I want something like this
            (if gameObject.x == -0.99){



            //activate obstacles
            int index = Random.Range(0, obstaclesToSpawn.Count);

            while(true){
                if (!obstaclesToSpawn[index].activeInHierarchy){
                    obstaclesToSpawn[index].SetActive(true);
                    obstaclesToSpawn [index].transform.position = transform.position;
                    break;
                }else{
                    index = Random.Range (0, obstaclesToSpawn.Count);
                }
            }

            StartCoroutine (SpawnRandomObstacle ());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, you need to save in each spawner the reference to other spawner.

```
public class ObstacleSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ObstacleSpawner otherSpawner;
    ...
```

Then in spawner check the position of obstacle in the second spawner. Something like this:

```
...
if (otherSpawner.obstaclesToSpawn[someIndex].transform.position.x <= -0.99)
{
    // Spawn new obstacle in this spawner...
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have implemented it now.

Comment: However, it is still in conflict with the IEnumerator, yield return new wait for seconds (3)

Comment: I'm glad that I've helped. But now it's seems like new unrelated problem. I would suggest to accept the answer to close this issue and create the new question with more info about new problem and new updated code.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing position of an object to a certain position in the world is something that might work for you right now but may cause problems in the future if you ever try to change anything in the way your scene is set up.

You're looking for distance travelled by an object and you have everything necessary to calculate said distance.

The starting point for all your obstacles spawned by an `ObstacleSpawner` is the position of the `ObstacleSpawner` object so you don't need to cache the spawn position which makes things a lot easier.

You need a variable defining the distance after which you want to spawn another obstacle something like `public float distBeforeNextObstacle = 1f`, then you can compare this distance against the obstacle's distance from its spawn position (use `Vector3` or `Vector2`, both have a [Distance](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html) method, you should choose whatever fits your game best):

```
if(Vector3.Distance(obstaclesToSpawn[index].transform.position, transform.position)>=distBeforeNextObstacle)
{
    //Spawn next obstacle
}
```